# Magento: How do I hide home button in navigation menu

Tags: magento

I'm using Magento Community edition, I want to remove or simply hide the 'home' button in the main navigation bar.

Reason being is that I have another page which is acting as the landing page for the site.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the default theme *doesn't* have a home link in the main navigation bar. The main nav is populated by categories by default.  Are you using a custom theme? If so, check your layout files and see if there is a reference to the home link.

Answer (score 0):

Home is not included in top navigation by default. It might be functionality in your theme or there might be a category created by name 'Home'.

Comment: Just to let you know I've inherited this site and I have no experience in Magento!. The navigation bar is in a static block but only lists the html code for links 3 to 9. Links 1 (home) and 2 aren't listed. I  changed the block's status to disabled to see if that would hide the entire menu, but the navigation bar is still displayed?